# POSTing XML with non-ASCII characters

Tags: http, post, non-ascii-characters, restsharp

I'm trying to patch [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/) for it to be able to `POST` XMLs with non-ASCII characters as `POST` request body.

Here's how it gets written:

```
private void WriteRequestBody(HttpWebRequest webRequest) {
    if (HasBody) {
        webRequest.ContentLength = RequestBody.Length;

        var requestStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream();
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(requestStream, Encoding.ASCII)) {
            writer.Write(RequestBody);
        }
    }
}
```

`RequestBody` is a string and when server actually tries to parse the request, all non-ASCII characters turn into `???`.

Now, I do the following:

```
var encoding = Encoding.UTF8;

webRequest.ContentLength = encoding.GetByteCount(RequestBody);

var requestStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream();
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(requestStream, encoding)) {
    writer.Write(RequestBody);
}
```

But it throws `IOException` on `Stream.Dispose()` saying "Cannot close stream until all bytes are written."

How do I post this XML?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used RestSharp but looking explanation my guess is that the payload's ContentLength does not match the internal-string. XML uses UTF-8 escapes, so the payload could become larger. So on original string the representation could  Content-Length could differ.

Maybe you calculate the Content-Length at a wrong place?